# Vectorized pythonic way to get count of elements greater than current element

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to compare every entry in array b with its respective column to find how many entries (from that column) are larger than the reference.  My code seems embarrassingly slow and I suspect it is due to for loops rather than vector operations.

Can we 'vectorize' the following code?

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
m = 200
b = np.random.rand(n,m)
p = np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range(0,n): #rows
   for j in range(0,m):  # cols
     r = b[i,j]  
     p[i,j] = ( ( b[:,j] > r).sum() ) / (n)
```

After some more thought, I think sorting each column would improve overall runtime by making the later comparisons much faster.

After some more searching I believe I want column-wise percentileofscore (http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html)

Comment: You could move the `/ n` out of the inner loop as that is simply a element-wise divide that could be done last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just needed a bit of deeper study to figure out that we could simply use `argsort()` indices along each column to get the count of greater than the current element at each iteration.

**Approach #1**

With that theory in mind, one solution would be simply using two `argsort`-ing to get the counts -

```
p = len(b)-1-b.argsort(0).argsort(0)
```

**Approach #2**

We could optimize it further, given the fact that the `argsort` indices are unique numbers. So, the second `argsort` step could use some array-assignment + `advanced-indexing`, like so -

```
def count_occ(b):
    n,m = b.shape     
    out = np.zeros((n,m),dtype=int)
    idx = b.argsort(0)
    out[idx, np.arange(m)] = n-1-np.arange(n)[:,None]
    return out
```

Finally, divide by `n` as noted in the question for both the approaches.

---

#### Benchmarking

Timing all the approaches posted thus far -

```
In [174]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: n = 1000
     ...: m = 200
     ...: b = np.random.rand(n,m)

In [175]: %timeit (len(b)-1-b.argsort(0).argsort(0))/float(n)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop

In [176]: %timeit count_occ(b)/float(n)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

# @Brad Solomon's soln
In [177]: %timeit np.sum(b > b[:, None], axis=-2) / float(n)
1 loop, best of 3: 349 ms per loop

# @marco romelli's loopy soln
In [178]: %timeit loopy_soln(b)/float(n)
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop
```

Comment: Now to shake things up.  Is this moddifiable for the reference value to come from outside the column?  My first task was as described in the question.  My next task is to repeat the process for a new array.  Every entry in new array is compared to entries in the original (for its respective column).  Essentially, the reference value is now from outside.  Does this warrant  a new question?

Comment: @Eruditio Yup, please post a new question, because that would require a re-thinking and using other NumPy tools at least for this solution.

Comment: Other good answers here but this worked well within my memory constraints.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some added space complexity, but one way to get to this would be to expand `b` to enable a broadcasted comparison and enable you to get rid of the (Python) loop entirely:

```
# for n = 10; m = 2; np.random.seed(444)
>>> np.sum(b > b[:, None], axis=-2) / n
array([[0.7, 0.1],
       [0.3, 0.6],
       [0. , 0.2],
       [0.4, 0.8],
       # ...
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(444)

def loop(b):
    # Could also use for (i, j), val in np.ndenumerate(b)
    p = np.zeros_like(b)
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, m):
            r = b[i, j]
            p[i, j] = ((b[:, j] > r).sum())
    return p / n

def noloop(b):
    n = b.shape[0]
    return np.sum(b > b[:, None], axis=-2) / n

n = 10
m = 2
b = np.random.rand(n, m)

assert np.allclose(loop(b), noloop(b))
# True

n = 1000
m = 200
b = np.random.rand(n, m)

%timeit loop(b)
# 1.59 s ± 50.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit -r 7 -n 1 noloop(b)
# 443 ms ± 18.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

assert np.allclose(loop(b), noloop(b))
# True
```

Comment: correct, kind of tricky / clever, but should not be so obscure... :)

Comment: I run into memory problems with this approach with b around 3000x600.  Part of it is my machine I'm sure but I will eventually need to get this to 10k x 1k.

Comment: Yes, going to leave this answer here for the time being but definitely prefer @Divakar's approach here.  The issue is that `b > b[:, None]` will be of shape (n, n, m) and size n x n x m, 5.4 billion in this case...

Answer (score 1):

I think the following solution is much faster:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
m = 200
b = np.random.rand(n,m)
p = np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range(m):
    col = []
    for j in range(n):
        col.append((j, b[j,i]))
    a = sorted(col, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for j in range(n):
        p[a[j][0], i] = j
```

It works column by column and is based on sorting, so with a fast guess I would say `O(nmlogn)`.

**EDIT**

Benchmark results

Original code: 1.46 s ± 8.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

This answer: 178 ms ± 295 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Yeah; I think a presort (once per column) is important for getting improvements out of this.  Now I need to check if percentileofscore does the sort as well.

Comment: I did a quick benchmark  and my code executes in around 225ms whereas yours in around 1.5 seconds. Let us know if `percentileofscore` allows you to go faster ;)

Comment: seems the faster solution for now, but you would be taken a lot more seriously if you did `%timeit` tests like the other soution (it is a magic command accessible in IPython environments) :)

Comment: If I wanted to compare an external reference value (instead of one from the column) could I just col.append((j, new_reference)) and the rest work as expected?

Comment: No I think you need more modifications to make that work. Probably sorting is not useful anymore in this case.