# Vectorized form to get count of elements greater than a reference

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

...and that reference comes from a separate matrix.

This question is an extension of an earlier answered question where the reference element came directly from the same column it was being compared against.  Some clever sorting and referencing the index of the sort seemed to solve that one.

Broadcasting has been suggested in both the original and this new question.  I run out of memory at around **`n ~ 3000`** and need **another order of magnitude** larger yet.

---

### The Target ( Production-grade ) Scaling Definitions:

So as to let proposed solutions' approaches fair and mutually comparable, both in the **`[SPACE]`**- and the **`[TIME]`**-domains,
let's assume **`n = 50000; m = 20; k = 50; a = np.random.rand( n, m ); ...`**

---

I'm now interested in a more general form where the reference value comes from another matrix of reference values.

Original question:

[Vectorized pythonic way to get count of elements greater than current element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880927/vectorized-pythonic-way-to-get-count-of-elements-greater-than-current-element/49882983?noredirect=1#comment86941320_49882983)

New question:  Can we write a vectorized form to perform the following role.

Function receives as input 2 2-d arrays.

```
A = n x m
B = k x m
```

and returns

```
C = k x m.
```

**`C[i,j]`** is the proportion of observations in **`A[:,j]`** ( just the `j`-th column ) that are larger than **`B[i,j]`**

Here is my embarrasingly slow double for loop implementation.

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
m = 20
k = 50
a = np.random.rand(n,m)
b = np.random.rand(k,m)
c = np.zeros((k,m))

for j in range(0,m): #cols
   for i in range(0,k):  # rows
     r = b[i,j]  
     c[i,j] = ( ( a[:,j] > r).sum() ) / (n)
```

Comment: Your recent **comment** about a [SPACE]-domain limit **ought have been already posted** since beginning in a fair and **c**omplete  M**C**VE-definition , **definitely not as** a form of **an objection against a solution** @MaxU has proposed. ( " *... I have large-ish values and I run **out of memory well before my full data set size**. – Eruditio 47 secs ago* " )

Comment: Thanks.  Noted in the description now. 
It still works (and taught me broadcasting) but I quickly run out of space.  The soln in other question was more up front with memory usage when suggesting a broadcast solution.

Comment: @Eruditio Would love some feedback on the `argsort` based solution on this Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Approach #1

We could again use the `argsort` trick as discussed in [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882983/3293881) but in a bit twisted manner. We would concatenate the second array into the first array and then perform `argsort-ing`. We need to use `argsort` for both the concatenated array and the second one and have our desired output. The implementation would look something like this -

```
ab = np.vstack((a,b))
len_a, len_b = len(a), len(b)
b_argoffset = b.argsort(0).argsort(0)
total_args = ab.argsort(0).argsort(0)[-len_b:]
out = len_a - total_args + b_argoffset
```

**Explanation**

1. Concatenate second array whose values are to be computed into the first array.
2. Now, since we are appending, we would have their index positions later on, after the first array length has ended.
3. We use one `argsort` to get the relative positions of the second array w.r.t to the entire concatenated array and one more `argsort` to trace back those indices w.r.t the original order.
4. We need to repeat the double `argsort-ing` for the second array on itself, so as to compensate for the concatenation.
5. These indices are for each element in `b` with the comparison : `a[:,j] > b[i,j]`. Now, these indices orders are 0-based, i.e. an index closer to `0` represent greater number of elements in `a[:,j]` than the current element `b[i,j]`, so a greater count and vice versa. So, we need to subtract those indices from the length of `a[:,j]` for the final output.

#### Approach #1 - Improvement

We would optimize it further by using `array-assignment`, again inspired by `Approach #2` from the same solution. So, those arg outputs : `b_argoffset` and `total_args` could be alternatively computed, like so -

```
def unqargsort(a):
    n,m = a.shape     
    idx = a.argsort(0)
    out = np.zeros((n,m),dtype=int)
    out[idx, np.arange(m)] = np.arange(n)[:,None]
    return out

b_argoffset = unqargsort(b)

total_args = unqargsort(ab)[-len_b:]
```

#### Approach #2

We could also leverage [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for an altogether different approach -

```
k,m = b.shape
sidx = a.argsort(0)
out = np.empty((k,m), dtype=int)
for i in range(m): #cols
    out[:,i] = np.searchsorted(a[:,i], b[:,i],sorter=sidx[:,i])
out = len(a) - out
```

**Explanation**

1. We get the sorted order indices for each column of `a`.
2. Then, use those indices to get how we could place values off `b` into the sorted `a` with `searcshorted`. This gives us same as the output from step#3,4 in  `Approach#1`.

Note that these approaches give us the count. So, for the final output, divide the output thus obtained  by `n`.

Comment: These work, I wish I knew why!  Maybe some more comments on whats going on with approach 1 and 3?  (2 is likely beyond me :p)

Comment: @Eruditio Added some explanation.

Comment: I think I like the searchsorted the best.  It required me to look up what searchsorted does, but once I did the process was clearer.  The double argsorting is still a bit of a head scratcher.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use broadcasting:

```
c = (a[:,None,:] > b).mean(axis=0)
```

Demo:

```
In [207]: n = 5

In [208]: m = 3

In [209]: a = np.random.randint(10, size=(n,m))

In [210]: b = np.random.randint(10, size=(n,m))

In [211]: c = np.zeros((n,m))

In [212]: a
Out[212]:
array([[2, 2, 8],
       [5, 0, 8],
       [2, 5, 7],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [2, 6, 7]])

In [213]: b
Out[213]:
array([[3, 6, 8],
       [2, 7, 5],
       [8, 9, 2],
       [9, 8, 7],
       [2, 7, 2]])

In [214]: for j in range(0,m): #cols
     ...:    for i in range(0,n):  # rows
     ...:      r = b[i,j]
     ...:      c[i,j] = ( ( a[:,j] > r).sum() ) / (n)
     ...:
     ...:

In [215]: c
Out[215]:
array([[0.4, 0. , 0. ],
       [0.4, 0. , 0.8],
       [0. , 0. , 1. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.4],
       [0.4, 0. , 1. ]])

In [216]: (a[:,None,:] > b).mean(axis=0)
Out[216]:
array([[0.4, 0. , 0. ],
       [0.4, 0. , 0.8],
       [0. , 0. , 1. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.4],
       [0.4, 0. , 1. ]])
```

check:

```
In [217]: ((a[:,None,:] > b).mean(axis=0) == c).all()
Out[217]: True
```

Comment: Broadcasting came up in the other thread as well.  I have large-ish values and I run out of memory well before my full data set size.

Comment: @Eruditio, yeah, this approach requieres additionally `m*n*n*8` bytes in RAM